# Symfony2 many-to-many for an existing ERD schema

Tags: many-to-many, doctrine-orm, symfony, erd

For an existing Entity-Relationship diagram, let's say we have Author and Book entities.

- Author can have published several Book;
- A Book can have several Author.

The database already exists. As the joining table (asso_book_author) is already here, how to manage it with Symfony & Doctrine ?

Thanks a lot by advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Annotations for Doctrine Entities? Hope so... ;-)

Here is an example from the Doctrine Annotations Reference Manual: 
http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-manytomany

```
<?php
/**
 * Owning Side
 *
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="features")
 * @JoinTable(name="user_groups",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $groups;
```

and

```
/**
 * Inverse Side
 *
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="groups")
 */
private $features;
```

Comment: What is curious is, aren't both sides owners when making a many-to-many relation ?

Comment: Yes.. You're right... Dont mention the terms... This is what you want. I think Doctrine does it this way, to have no repeating parts like @JoinTable.

Comment: According to Doctrine documentation [link](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-side-and-inverse-side) in ManyToMany relation configured that way one side is owner and other inverse side. Documentation tells that you can have two owner sides in ManyToMany relation, but doesn't show any example. I've tried several annotation combinations but without a success - one side is always owner and other inverse side.